# How to show errors in sqlplus

Tags: oracle, compiler-errors, sqlplus

I would like to know how to show errors in sqlplus.

1. try to compile a view

   `alter view SYS.DBA_XML_SCHEMAS compile;`
2. I have the message :

   ```
   ERROR at line 1:

   ORA-04063 : view altered with compilation errors.
   ```
3. I try :

   `show errors;`
4. it says :

   ```
   No errors
   ```
5. I try :

   ```
   show errors view SYS.DBA_XML_SCHEMAS
   ```
6. it says :

   ```
   LINE/COL  ERROR

   0/0       ORA-00942 : table or view does not exist
   ```

If I could compile with errors, the view must exist or it would tell me that the view does not exist. I dont know how to display the compilation errors of the view

thank you

Comment: What happens when you try `SELECT * FROM SYS.DBA_XML_SCHEMAS`?

Comment: Why are you compiling a SYS view?

Comment: I know when SQL*Plus is sparse on throwing error messages for compiling views, I will just run the SQL associated with the view and the error handling message will be more verbose (e.g. line and error thrown).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can query the `dba_errors` view, or the `all_errors` view, directly; the SQL*Plus `show errors` command seems to be a wrapper around that anyway.

```
select line, position, attribute, text
from dba_errors
where owner = 'SYS'
and type = 'VIEW'
and name = 'DBA_XML_SCHEMAS'
order by sequence;
```

But based on what `show errors` is telling you, that will just show the same thing, error "ORA-00942 : table or view does not exist" from line 0 position 0.

That doesn't make much sense, but internal views are sometimes strange things, and attempting to recompile one is probably not a good idea.

You might need to get your DBA to run [`utlrp.sql` to recompile all invalid objects](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/scripts002.htm#i1005727) in the database. As with anything you think of doing under the SYS schema, that should be done with care; and only if selecting from the view still says it's invalid and failed recompilation.