# warning: procedure created with compilation errors sql3

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I created two tables, album and personnage, and the third one contains references but it returns this error:

> Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

What is the problem.? How to solve it.?

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TT1_AJOUTE_PERSON_DANS_ALBUM(pnump in number , pnuma in number) 
--paramètres à préciser
 IS
 v_pers number;
 v_alb number;

 BEGIN
 select count(a.numa) into v_alb
 from tt1_album a
where (a.numa=pnuma);

if(v_alb=0) then
dbms_output.put_line('album introuvable');
end if;

select count(p.nump) into v_pers
from tt1_peronnage p
where (p.nump=pnump);

if(v_pers=0) then
dbms_output.put_line('personnage introuvable');
end if;

 if(v_pers=1 and v_alb=1 ) then
insert into tt1_abl_pers values((select ref(a) from tt1_album a 
where(a.numa=pnuma));
(select ref(p) from tt1_personnage p where(p.nump=pnump)));
end if;

END ;
 /
```

when i run the commnd show errors it returns [image: this error]

Comment: Have you defined the function `ref()`?

Comment: yes ill defined

Comment: Run the `SHOW ERRORS` command in SQL*Plus to, well, show the error(s).

Comment: You have an invalid line before the final 'END IF'. Can't really see what it is intended to be. Looks like it is meant to be part of the insert.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show errors in sqlplus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25247461/how-to-show-errors-in-sqlplus)

Comment: i have updated the question

Comment: Please look at the line numbers it mentions. you have a semi-colon instead of a comma for the insert. As the message suggests.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by this piece of your code:

> insert into tt1_abl_pers values((select ref(a) from tt1_album a 
>   where(a.numa=pnuma)); (select ref(p) from tt1_personnage p
>   where(p.nump=pnump)));

I suppose that you are going to insert values of function results [ref(a) and ref(p)] to table tt1_abl_pers:

```
INSERT INTO tt1_abl_pers
(ref)
SELECT ref(a) FROM tt1_album a WHERE(a.numa=pnuma)
UNION ALL
SELECT ref(p ) FROM tt1_personnage p WHERE(p.nump=pnump);
```