# Unable to see error description in SQL plus

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, sqlplus

I am new to oracle and using SQL plus terminal to access oracle DB. I tried to create one function and it returned warning that

> `function created with compilation error`

When I executed `show errors` it always showing

ERROR:

> `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`

My function :

```
create or replace function axsaum.get_name
AS
v_name varchar2(20);
begin
v_name:='Helloooooo';
dbms_output.put_line(v_name);
END;
/
```

Please suggest.

Comment: check this link :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25247461/how-to-show-errors-in-sqlplus

Comment: I tried executing utlurl.sql file. But its not working the file thrown error as Warning: Package created with compilation errors.

Answer (score 1):

You have the error message:  `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`. This means your function contains a reference to a database object which the compiler is unable to associate to a table or view **within the scope of the function**.

There are several reasons why you might get this.

1. Your function references a table or view which exists in the schema but you have misspelled its name.
2. Your function references a table or view which exists in a different schema and you have not prefixed the reference with the owning schema and there is no synonym either.
3. Your function references a table or view which exists in a different schema but the schema owner has not granted you rights on that object.
4. Your function references a table or view which exists in a different schema and the schema owner has granted you rights on that object **through a role**. The Oracle security model means that we cannot build database objects (views, stored procedures, etc) using privileges granted to our account through a role. The privileges have to be explicitly granted to our named account.
5. The object does not exist in your schema or another.

The first two causes are ones you can fix by yourself. The others would  require the intervention of the schema owner, or a power user with admin privileges (such as a DBA).

---

Now that you've posted your function, we can see that you are referencing an Oracle built-in package, DBMS_OUTPUT. Now that package should be installed and granted as part of a default install. But if you have a non-standard install or have accidentally dropped or revoked something you will need to get the SYS user to run the `dbmsotpt.sql` script which should fix it. The details are covered in the package's documentation. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_output.htm#ARPLS67302).

Comment: Eventhough I specify the proper schema name in function and proper privileges  I have provided, also I am getting the same error. I tried to create a function also another trigger , both trowing the same error, whether any .sql default files I need to execute like catproc.sql ???

Comment: Please check my function and its not having any tables. Then why its throwing that table doesn't exist error, when execute show errors query?

Comment: Oracle often uses old messages in new contexts; looks like that's the situation here.

Comment: Also i am not able to use user_errors and dba_errors table and getting below error.SQL> select * from user_errors;
select * from user_errors
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: Okay, so it sounds like you have got a improperly installed database. In case, yes you should run `catproc.sql`.  Sorry it took so long to get here but your original question lacked these crucial details. The teaching is, the more complete your question the more likely you are to get a helpful and timely response.